# How to show title, image and description when sharing a link on slack using Meta tag in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

I add the meta tag in my project and its working well on localhost and live website. But my hosted projects share in slack not display the title and description content. How to solve this type of issue

```
    <MetaTags>
            <title>{TITLE}</title>
            <meta name="description" content={pageDescription} />
            <meta property="og:title" content={pageTitle} />
            <meta property="og:image" content="images/logo-square.png" />
    </MetaTags>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how load those meta data, if you are using react app and adding those meta data in component, it won't work.
As React is single page application, when you share anything on any app like slack, facebook, twitter etc. they search for meta data from head of website by making on request when you send link on those applications.
They don't load website on any browser, that will render react application and get those meta tags.
You have to provide meta tags on server level response sender.